# what does response "50" only mean for diagnostic request "10 02" switching to programming session?

Tags: can-bus, diagnostics

I have to enter programming session to test some functionalities, but i face 3 different scenarios each time..
*sending the request"10 02"
1- getting positive response "50 02 xx xx xx xx"
2- getting negative response "7F 10 22" 
3-first getting negative response "7F 10 22" and then getting "50"
the QU: what does "50" mean? 
and another QU: what may make the programming session not entered? what is the preconditions that should be happened?

Comment: What is the context? What is "programming sessions"? And more importantly what is your programming question? Troubleshooting the use of some random unknown CAN-based protocol isn't on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be UDS based diagnostics.

The first byte of the request - `0x10` in your case - is the service ID. In UDS `0x10` is for session handling.

The first byte of a positive response is always `0x40 + <service id>`. Thus `0x50` in your example.

When a request to enter a programming session is denied is mostly application specific. 
E.g. you may need to authorize first. Or you may be going full speed on the highway and thus reprogramming the engine control is not a good idea.